# Does this really violate MVC Separation of Concerns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, separation-of-concerns

Simple question. I must be totally wrong but I thought worth asking this question.

Is accessing ViewData[“Message”] within the View correct according to separation of concerns described in MVC?

For example, in Controller:

```
ViewData[“Message”] =  “Display this message”;
```

Within View we call

```
<%= ViewData[“Message”]  %>
```

The alternative (does not violates Separation of Concerns) is to have the Message set in the view model.

For example in Controller:

```
UserViewModel.Message = “Display this message”
```

Within View we call

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UserViewModel>" %>
<%= Html.TextBox("Message", Model Message)%>
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `ViewData` and `Model` is that the former is untyped property bag and the latter is a strongly typed object. But they both act as 'models' for your `View`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how these should be different, other than the last one being strongly typed? You pass data along to the view, and let the view do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

To me, I think the concept of all three (ViewData, ViewBag and TempData) is a violation of MVC. Very convenient to use but not following the diagram [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx).

The View shouldn't know what the Controller is passing. I actually [asked the same question just a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548090/viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata-violates-mvc) and then I found this post.