# ViewData, ViewBag and TempData violates MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If we all look at the mvc diagram, the view shouldn't know the models the controller gives out to (according to msdn mvc overview https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx). To me, the ViewData, ViewBag, and TempData violates this and I have been scratching my head at why these three concepts was introduced.

Maybe I am getting it wrong? I can easily pass data to the view using the models instead of these three.

Would like to know other people's opinion.

If you down vote please comment why.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I can easily pass data to the view using the models instead of these
>   three.

Yes definitely you can and in such case your view becomes a strongly typed view and you can see starting of your view has a line

```
@Model entityName
```

What if you don't want (for some reason) your view to be strongly typed at all. How do you think in such case you are going to pass the data to view.

That's the purpose of `ViewData` or `ViewBaG` or `TempData`.

> the view shouldn't know the models the controller gives out to

I think you misinterpreted this line which can't be agreed upon. If your view needs data to be displayed in controls (may be an edit view), then from where it's going to get the data if it doesn't know from where to read the data.

View someway or other way must know the model data (either in form of directly passing the Model object or using any of those 3 technique).

**EDIT:**

Per your last comment:

> can i not use this?

```
public class TestModel 
{ 
    public dynamic testproperty { get; set; } 
}
```

Yes, probably you can but that's not a proper way. Try creating a strongly typed view with model as `TestModel` and use any scaffold template and see if scaffolding can generate a proper template.

It will not, since scaffolding internally uses reflection to go through your model properties and accordingly generate controls for those properties/members. Since you have a dynamic property, it will not be able to reflect that property. change the type to a static type like `String` and see it will generate a `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.testproperty)`. *That's the issue*.

Even if you don't use any scaffolding template and generate controls by your hand; what type of control will you generate for your property? since it's tped as `dynamic` it could be anything (`string`, `int`, `datetime`, `email`...).

`ViewBag` or `ViewData` are state management technique to pass on small amount of data b/w the views or controller to views. You should always pass your data as Model object to your view as correctly stated by @SteveHarris.

Hope this makes t clear to some sense.

Comment: can i not use this? `public class TestModel
    {
        public dynamic testproperty { get; set; }
    }` what i did with ours is every view is tied to a model. nice thing about this approach is if there is a name change, the view will know about it. using ViewBag, ViewData and TempData will require the view to know the name of the key.

Comment: The view should be aware if the model. The view is built from the data in the model, the view passes data in the form of the model to the controller. The controller accepts the data and applies whatever business logic, validation, etc.

Comment: @avatart0ph, See edit in answer to clarify your comment.